# why iterator is not throwing concurrentmodification exception?

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrentmodification

why does this method not throw a concurrent modification? 
if if(next.equals("3") it does not. However, i change it to equals("1") it does. what is happening here?

```
    private void checkConcurrentModification(){

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("1", 1);
        map.put("2", 2);
        map.put("3", 3);


        Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String next = iterator.next().getKey();
            map.put(next, 1);
            if(next.equals("3")){ //does not throw exception
 //if(next.equals("1")){ //throws exception
                map.put("4", 4);
            }
        }

        for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("entry key and value" +entry.getKey() + " : " +entry.getValue());
        }

    }


prints:
entry key and value1 : 1
entry key and value2 : 1
entry key and value3 : 1
entry key and value4 : 4
```

Comment: I'm getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` for the example as written (with `3`).

Comment: nope. calling from main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the the implementation of `HashMap`.

If you run this under Java 7, then with the `if (next.equals("3"))` it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, and with `1`, it won't.

If you run this under Java 8, then with `3` it will not throw the exception, and with `1`, it will.

The reason for this is that when you iterate the map under Java 7, the first key is going to be the `3` and the last is `1`. So you are modifying the value while you still have other values to iterate.

Under Java 8, the first key in the iteration is `1` and the last is `3`.

If you modify the map when you have encountered the last key, it will not check that modification, because it only checks it the next time you try to call `next()`, but after the last value, `hasNext()` returns false, so `next()` is not called and the exception is avoided.

Comment: _If you run this under Java 8, then with 3 it will not throw the exception, and with 1, it will._ I'm using  Java 8. But its not happening.

Comment: Thanks. Upon further inspection of the HashIterator class, calling hasNext on the iterator (hashIterator) only checks if next != null. 
However,    
the next() method checks  
 if (modCount != expectedModCount)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
and thats why the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The `ConcurrentModificationException` is not thrown until you try to access `iterator.next().getKey();` after changing the map within the loop. In the example `"3"` is the last key in the original map and the loop is exited before the exception is thrown. For every key in the original map except the last one, the exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

`ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when the iterator reach the next map key, if you added a new key to the map at the previous step. So you only get the exception if the key you test is not the last one in the map. In your case `3` is for sure the last one.

Note: As `HashMap` has no order, on one machine `3` might be last, on others `1` or `2` might be.