# Why am I able to call remove in a for-each loop?

Tags: java, foreach, concurrentmodification, concurrentmodificationexception

```
ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
collection.add("Apple");
collection.add("Banana");
collection.add("Cherry");
for (String element : collection) 
{
    if (element.equals("Banana")) {
        collection.remove(element);
    }
}
```

If it's true then why does the above snippet work fine? It doesn't throw a concurrentModification error like I was expecting it to.

Comment: Try it with a fourth element in the collection... basically, the conditions under which the exception will be thrown aren't guaranteed, but it's simply not *safe* to call `remove` while iterating like this.

Comment: I believe this was asked some times... maybe like [why iterator is not throwing concurrentmodification exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35100455/85421) or (more like related) [Behavior of concurrentmodification exception ? how iterator internally works.Why exception is not thrown in second case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36772177/85421)

Comment: or better [Why am I not getting a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8189466/85421)

Answer (score 1):

You are able to call the remove because you aren't hitting the portion of the code that would throw the exception(ArrayList checkForComodification method). This has to do with how for-each loops use internal iterators. (Oracle doc about that here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) By removing an element from the second to last position you are causing the next iteration method to returns false. This in turn causes the code checking for concurrent modification to not be triggered.